# CentOS 6: Can not start NFS

Tags: centos6, nfs

I am unable to start the NFS service. When starting there is no error. But the services are stopt after it. No messages at all in /var/log/messages. Same happens to rpcbind serivce. Any idea what this could be? I also tried to disable iptables.

```
[root@server1 ~]# service nfs start
[root@server1 ~]# service nfs status
rpc.svcgssd is stopped
rpc.mountd is stopped
nfsd is stopped
rpc.rquotad is stopped

[root@server1 ~]# service rpcbind start
[root@server1 ~]# service rpcbind status
rpcbind is stopped

[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/exports 
/tmp *(ro)

[root@server1 ~]# chkconfig --list | egrep '(rpcbind|nfs)'
nfs             0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
nfslock         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcbind         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. Looks like the `/etc/syconfig/network` file had dos characters in it..

```
dos2unix /etc/sysconfig/network
```

solved it.

Comment: What turned you on to this solution?

Comment: I was debugging the start with sh -x /etc/init.d/nfs start. It showed some akward dos-style characters in it.

Answer (score 2):

in case anyone comes across this...  I had the exact same symptoms with oracle / red hat 6.4 install and basic nfs setup.  service start rpcbind, no response and service always stopped.  Same with service nfs start.  echo $? gave back a 6.  This link led me to look at the startup script and in my case was failing at:

```
# Check that networking is up.
[ "${NETWORKING}" != "yes" ] && exit 6
```

After putting in

```
NETWORKING=yes
```

in /etc/sysconfig/network nfs would start.